# Eclipse is being opened by default when i start system?

Tags: eclipse

Whenever i start system eclipse is being opened by default even i don't need it.Every time i am killing eclipse process after starting the system.What went wrong with my eclipse ? Please help me.I am using fedora 12 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

> Win: run->msconfig->startup->uncheck eclipe.exe
>
> Linux: remove Eclipse from /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Comment: What can i do with sudo gedit /etc/fstab.Can u please explain it.

Comment: try removing Eclipse from >/etc/rc.d/rc.local

Comment: There is no eclipse related entry in rc.local

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows, I think your eclipse.exe has been added to startup path of your system.

Go to Start->AllPrograms->Startup   then delete eclipse.exe from there.

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I am using linux ( fedora 12 )

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's a session-manager running that is restoring a previously saved session that included Eclipse. Alas, I don't know anything about Fedora, but perhaps this new keyword helps you in your search.

There should be a menu item somewhere that allows you to inspect/edit the session settings.